# How to use Amazon S3 inside a nodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-credentials

I am trying to use Amazon S3 to upload/download some images and videos from inside my locally running NodeJS application. But when I search for that, there are tons of different code snippets and different credential management approaches and I am totally confused by that.

I created an IAM user and I have `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_BUCKET_NAME` in my `.env` file but I think it's not a good approach using `.env` file in my app and it's better I use [temporary token credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html). But I don't know how?

What is the minimum secure code I can use to do that?

Comment: You could also make use of environmental variables?

I am not sure if any similar libraries exist, but try looking for encrypted credentials, similar to RoR for NodeJS. Basically, it encrypts your details in a credentials.yml.enc file, which can then be access via the Rails helper.

Comment: @AshvithShetty: So you say using a `.env` file for credentials is a common way of doing that?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that most platforms also have option to set environmental variables without the need for .env file, which can then be accessed by the web app you've deployed.

Comment: @AshvithShetty: Right! But I am trying to take this approach: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/prog-services-sts.html , Although I am completely new to AWS and have no idea what I should to do?

Answer (score 2):

Read the ***AWS SDK for JavaScript V3 Developer Guide***. There are many examples and yes - using creds is a standard practice.

[What's the AWS SDK for JavaScript?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/welcome.html)

A topic you should read is https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html

Comment: I followed your suggested links but they're for Java not Java/TypeScript.

Comment: These links are for JavaScript - not Java. There is a NodeJS topic in the guide I linked too as well -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/node-js-considerations.html

Comment: At `Next steps` section of https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup.html#setup-credentials it builds something in Java. I don't know what to do if I use JavaScript? Also in other JS/NodeJS related links I can not see something similar to these steps!

Comment: Why are you referring to the Java DEV Guide? Your thread says you want to work in NodeJS.  You should be reading the JavaScript V3 DEV guide. The creds section in the JavaScript guide is here -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials.html

Comment: `Loading credentials in Node.js from IAM roles for Amazon EC2`
    `Loading credentials for a Node.js Lambda function`
    `Loading credentials in Node.js from the shared credentials file`
    `Loading credentials in Node.js from environment variables`
    `Loading credentials in Node.js using a configured credential process`

Comment: Which one is the better approach?

Comment: I personally use shared creds in my AWS programs. That is, a credentials file that have my keys,